# Pull up Generic Type to interface

Tags: c#

I have an `IModule` interface defined as below:

```
    public interface IModule
    {
        //Properties
        string StoreName { get; set; }
    
        void Execute();

        T ApiClient; // <-- How do I do this?
    }
```

I also have an abstract class defined as:

```
    public abstract class ModuleBase<T> : IModule where T : IAPIClient
    {
        public T ApiClient { get; private set; }

        public abstract Task Execute();
    }
```

I then inherit `ModuleBase` in a class such as:

```
    public class DemoModule : ModuleBase<DemoApiClient>
    {
        public override string StoreName => "Demo"

        public override async Task Execute(){
           ApiClient.DoStuff();
           //... some long running stuff here
        } 
    }
```

`DemoApiClient` is defined as:

```
public class DemoApiClient : IAPIClient
{
    public IProxyManger ProxyManager {get; set;}
    public IHttpClient  HttpClient   {get; set;}
    
    public void DoStuff() {
       Console.Log("DemoApiClient - DoStuff");
    }
}
```

`IAPIClient` is an interface with the following declarations:

```
    public interface IAPIClient
    {
        IProxyManager ProxyManager { get; }

        IHTTPClient HttpClient { get; }
    }
```

How can I pull up the generic `ApiClient` on `ModuleBase` up to `IModule`? I want to ensure that every implementation of `IModule` can implement the implementation of `IAPIClient`?

The reason I need this is because of the following example:

```
IModule module = (IModule)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(DemoModule));
module.ApiClient.DoStuff()
```

Note that `DoStuff()` is specific to `DemoApiClient` and other implementations of `IAPIClient` will contain methods specific to them. For this reason, I cannot pull up `DoStuff()` to `IAPIClient`.

Comment: `IModule` means one thing, it have an `string StoreName { get; }`,
So not every implementation of `IModule` will have for sure `ApiClient`

Comment: Its not entirely clear wht `IModule` needs APIClient at all - your generic s only on the base class.

Comment: I think you're right. I'm going to change it to pass around an `IAPIClient` instead

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `IModule` generic

```
public interface IModule<T> where T : IApiClient
{    
    Task Execute();

    T ApiClient {get;}
}
```

Then:

```
public abstract class ModuleBase<T> : IModule<T> where T : IAPIClient
{
    public T ApiClient { get; private set; }

    public abstract Task Execute();
}
```

You'll need to know the type:

```
DemoModule module = (DemoModule)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(DemoModule));
module.ApiClient.DoStuff()
```

---

But lets take a step back here; why do you think `IModule` needs to know about the APIClient at all, when you never use it outside of the base class?

You original code should work just fine as you only call `ApiClient.DoStuff();` from `Execute`

Comment: Thanks! And how do I use `IModule` as a parameter? e.g. `public Test(IModule module) {
   module.ApiClient....
}`

Comment: You can't - once you go generic it needs to be carried throught everything (AKA generic hell). `public void Test<T>(IModule<T> module) where T: IAPIClient`

Comment: @Sam see my update, I think you're going down the wrong path

Answer (score -1):

Add `IAPIClient` property to `IModule`:

```
public interface IModule<T> where T : IAPIClient
{
    //Properties
    string StoreName { get; }

    T ApiClient { get; }
}
```

And `DoStuff` to `IAPIClient`:

```
public interface IAPIClient
{
    IProxyManager ProxyManager { get; }

    IHttpClient HttpClient { get; }

    void DoStuff();
}
```

And you can do this:

```
IModule module = (IModule)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(DemoModule));
module.ApiClient.DoStuff();
```

Comment: From the question _"Note that DoStuff() is specific to DemoApiClient and other implementations of IAPIClient will contain methods specific to them"_